# Convert CSV to JSON while dropping certain columns

Tags: python, json, csv, merge

I downloaded a dataset from OECD on income inequality as a csv file. I want to only keep the data on: LOCATION, TIME, VALUE.

This is what part of the head of the CSV looks like:

```
"LOCATION","INDICATOR","SUBJECT","MEASURE","FREQUENCY","TIME","Value","Flag Codes"
"AUS","INCOMEINEQ","GINI","INEQ","A","2014",0.337,
"AUS","INCOMEINEQ","GINI","INEQ","A","2016",0.33,
"AUT","INCOMEINEQ","GINI","INEQ","A","2014",0.274,
"AUT","INCOMEINEQ","GINI","INEQ","A","2015",0.276,
"AUT","INCOMEINEQ","GINI","INEQ","A","2016",0.284,
```

This is my converter code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Universal CSV to JSON converter with scalability options"""

__author__      = "Tim Verlaan 11669128"

import csv  
import json  

def convert():
    """Convert CSV file to JSON file"""

    # Open the CSV  
    f = open( 'data.csv')  

    # Change each fieldname to the appropriate field name.    
    reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "LOCATION","INDICATOR","SUBJECT","MEASURE","FREQUENCY","TIME","Value","Flag Codes" ))  

    # skip the header 
    next(reader)

    # Parse the CSV into JSON  
    out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )  

    # Save the JSON  
    f = open( 'data_oecd.json', 'w')  
    f.write(out)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Separating the function, for scalability purposes"""

    convert()
```

Result now:

`[{"LOCATION": "AUS", "INDICATOR": "INCOMEINEQ", "SUBJECT": "GINI", "MEASURE": "INEQ", "FREQUENCY": "A", "TIME": "2014", "Value": "0.337", "Flag Codes": ""}, {"LOCATION": "AUS", "INDICATOR": "INCOMEINEQ", "SUBJECT": "GINI", "MEASURE": "INEQ", "FREQUENCY": "A", "TIME": "2016", "Value": "0.33", "Flag Codes": ""}, {"LOCATION": "AUT", "INDICATOR": "INCOMEINEQ", "SUBJECT": "GINI", "MEASURE": "INEQ", "FREQUENCY": "A", "TIME": "2014", "Value": "0.274", "Flag Codes": ""}, {"LOCATION": "AUT", "INDICATOR": "INCOMEINEQ", "SUBJECT": "GINI", "MEASURE": "INEQ", "FREQUENCY": "A", "TIME": "2015", "Value": "0.276", "Flag Codes": ""}, {"LOCATION": "AUT", "INDICATOR": "INCOMEINEQ", "SUBJECT": "GINI", "MEASURE": "INEQ", "FREQUENCY": "A", "TIME": "2016", "Value": "0.284", "Flag Codes": ""}`

Wanted result:

```
[{"LOCATION": "AUS", "TIME": 2014, "VALUE": 0.337}, {"LOCATION": "AUS", "TIME": 2016, "VALUE": 0.33}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df[['LOCATION', 'TIME', 'Value']].to_json(orient='records')
```

the `orient='records'` part is important, otherwise it will be grouped by columns instead of rows

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the required keys in the list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    out = [{"LOCATION": row['LOCATION'],"TIME": row["TIME"], "VALUE": ["Value"]} for row in reader]

with open('data_oecd.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(out, outfile)                       #Write to JSON.
```

**Output:**

```
[{'LOCATION': 'AUS', 'TIME': '2014', 'VALUE': ['Value']},
 {'LOCATION': 'AUS', 'TIME': '2016', 'VALUE': ['Value']},
 {'LOCATION': 'AUT', 'TIME': '2014', 'VALUE': ['Value']},
 {'LOCATION': 'AUT', 'TIME': '2015', 'VALUE': ['Value']},
 {'LOCATION': 'AUT', 'TIME': '2016', 'VALUE': ['Value']}]
```

Comment: How could I implement this as efficiently as possible in my already existing code?

Comment: I get this error

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 6, in <module>
    out = [{"LOCATION": row['LOCATION'],"TIME": row["TIME"], "VALUE": ["Value"]} for row in reader]
  File "converter.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    out = [{"LOCATION": row['LOCATION'],"TIME": row["TIME"], "VALUE": ["Value"]} for row in reader]
KeyError: 'LOCATION' ```

Comment: Looks like you do not have a header called `"LOCATION"` in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas and select only required column

```
 import pandas as pd

 df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
 df1 =df.loc[:,['LOCATION','TIME','VALUE']]
```